# Magento Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token <

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ajax, jquery

I have this function:

```
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event)
{
    $blockID = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $js = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '".Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/index/generate/')."', 
                        method: 'GET', 
                        data: {FeedId : ".$blockID."}}).success(function(){
                            alert ('Generation Successful!'); 
                            }).error(function(){
                                alert ('Generation Failed!'); 
                });
        </script>";
    $block = $event->getBlock();
    $test= Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
    if($test)
    {
        foreach($test as $currentFeed)
        {
            if($blockID == $currentFeed->getData('id'))
            {
                $link = $currentFeed->getData('filename');
                $block->addButton('Download', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Download'),
                    'onclick'   => "window.open('http://test.com".$link."', '_blank', 'Download')"
                ), -1);
                $block->addButton('Generate', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Generate Feed'),
                    'onclick'   => $js,
                    'class'     => 'go'
                ), -1);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

And I am getting an error when I try to click the Generate button, the error is:

> (index):646 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

And I am not sure why, the problem is with my $js value, but it seems correct, what could actually cause this error? I know it is something simple but I can not figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I created a script function after the php and the problem was that the js files were not loading.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery.noConflict();

function generateFeed(feedId) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/index/generate/') ?>", 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: {FeedId : feedId}
    }).success(function() {
        alert ('Generation Successful!'); 
    }).error(function() {
        alert ('Generation Failed!'); 
    });
}
```

I just called this function and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried concatenating the string, or assigning the values one by one?

You also need to `echo` the values in PHP.

```
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event)
{
$blockID = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');


$js = "<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '". echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/index/generate/'); . "', 
                    method: 'GET', 
                    data: {FeedId : ". echo $blockID . "}}).success(function(){
                        alert ('Generation Successful!'); 
                        }).error(function(){
                            alert ('Generation Failed!'); 
            });
    </script>";
$block = $event->getBlock();
$dreamAgility = Mage::getModel('dreamagility/dreamagility')->getCollection();
if($dreamAgility)
{
    foreach($dreamAgility as $currentFeed)
    {
        if($blockID == $currentFeed->getData('id'))
        {
            $link = $currentFeed->getData('filename');
            $block->addButton('Download', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Download'),
                'onclick'   => "window.open('http://dreamagilityshop.com".$link."', '_blank', 'Download')"
            ), -1);
            $block->addButton('Generate', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Generate Feed'),
                'onclick'   => $js,
                'class'     => 'go'
            ), -1);
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, it is not working with concatenating or echo